# ASP.NET MVC Memory Issue in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, memory-leaks

We are having memory issues in production for MVC 5 application.
I have analyzed the memory using .NET Memory Profiler 5.0. Below are some of the findings.

Analysis :

1. List which was created on the first page is still in memory after 4 pages even after garbage collection done 3 times.
2. Memory is not comming down after navigating from one page to other, it is going up as can be seen from the graph below.
3. .NET Memory gives lot of warnings of dataContext disposed but not garbage collected. When I saw the root graph, it is held by some delegate(please do correct me if my understanding is correct.)

Please refer the screen shots

[image: Memory Usage Graph]

[image: Object is held in memory]

[image]

What can be done to prevent it.
I have used using block in DAL and then mapped the data based entity to VM before passing to view.